# Minecraft command block: allow user on server to spawn one animal (per user)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like to create a quest where a user can activate a command block that will spawn one ocelot, but limit it so that each player can activate said command only once.

I've got the command to spawn one ocelot, which is:

```
/summon ocelot ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1}
```

but I don't know how to limit it so that each player can only do it only once. I found [the solution to something similar](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/347646-how-to-make-command-activate-only-once), but I don't know how to integrate that into spawning animals rather than giving items.

TL;DR: How would I use a command block to allow each player to summon an ocelot only once?

Comment: Without reviewing the research you've done, what I can say is you want to `tag` players that have spawned an animal, and then use that tag to prevent them from doing the same in the future. Note that this can be bypassed by ops.

Comment: Hey, look, an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353011)! Try asking about why ocelots don't spawn instead and give more details for that (in a new question).

Comment: What exactly is your question here? How to replace `/give` with `/summon`? Just… do it. Just replace it. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @FabianRöling that won't work because you don't `/summon` a player. The player argument is no longer included in the `/summon` command, but it needs to be included in order for it to only allow one command per player. Unless I'm looking at it wrong.

Comment: "The player argument is no longer included in the /summon command" What? What would that even do? Summoning a player?

Answer (score 1):

## Scoreboards!

You can track a user with scoreboards. The main gist is:

> If a user has an `hasOcelot` score of 1 presses the button, do nothing.
>   If a user has an `hasOcelot` score of 0 presses the button, spawn an Ocelot.
>   Give the current player who pressed the button a score for `hasOcelot` of 1.

Where `hasOcelot` is a score of type 'dummy' that you use to keep tabs on who has spawned an Ocelot and who hasn't.

You can use the `/testfor` command with the radius and score selectors to see if the player fits into the criteria.

---

## tl;dr

> Chain command blocks like this:
>
>  `/testfor @p[r=2,score_hasOcelot_max=0]` (Check if user hasn't spawned)
>  `/summon ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:Ocelot` (Summon if the previous `/testfor` was true)
>  `/scoreboards players set @p[r=2,score_hasOcelot_max=0] hasOcelot 1` (mark him as having an ocelot spawned, continuation of chain)
>
>  Note: I might've messed up some selectors due to changes between 1.9 and now.

Comment: `testfor` was removed in 1.13.  Also, this probably won't work in a function file because it relies on conditional execution.  Not a deal breaker, but generally makes life easier.  And the selectors are wrong for 1.13.

Comment: @MBraedley I haven't used commands in 1.13 yet, so if you have a better answer, by all means change it... Or post your own.